# Unable to access element from array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to access the specific elements of an array of JSON objects. To test I simply have:

```
{console.log(this.state.stockCharts)}
```

This returns (in browser):

[image: Returning the JSON]

This is great, but now I want to access a specific element. Say the first element. I type:

```
{console.log(this.state.stockCharts[0])}
```

And the browser is like: nah mate

```
undefined
```

It's probably something really simple, but I have been banging my head against my keyboard for the past 45 minutes and nothing has worked. Thanks guys!

**Edit 1 (For Akrion)**

The query that I am using to access the API is:

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo
```

This is what I get back from the call:

[image: Calling Alpha Advantage API]

I call this API twice, and after I get a response back I push it to my stockCharts array:

```
this.state.stockCharts.push(result)
```

**Edit 2 (For Beginner)**

I initialize the state how you would normally do it:

```
this.state = {
        stockCharts: []
}
```

Comment: Can you `JSON.stringify(this.state.stockCharts)` and post also the input?

Comment: Is that JSON? Like this.state.stockCharts[0]["Weekly Time Series"]? Never seen gaps like that in keys.

Comment: could you please both in the same time {console.log(this.state.stockCharts,this.state.stockCharts[0])} for just testing purpose

Comment: it’s not right JSON object. If it is then the keys should be enclosed in quotes but your json seems to be invalid eh: 1. Information should be “1. Information”. validate your JSON online I am sure it’s invalid

Comment: @Akrion When I do JSON.stringify(this.state.stockCharts) I get back `[ ]` as the return. The input is a query that I send to a foreign API. For this instance, I have called the API twice, each time returns one of these objects. When they arrive I push them to my stockCharts array

Comment: @JanakaDissanayake When I do this get the same thing `[ ] undefined` where that `[ ]` expanded is my full object array

Comment: @bflynnigan you said you call an API and get this as a result? Is it a rest API? What does the response of this API look like?

Comment: @Akrion I have posted an update with some more info. The API I am calling is a REST API (I am pretty sure)

Comment: include the code where you initialize/filled your variable `this.state`

Comment: Are you running the logic and setting the state to whatever the async JSON stuff is, in a componentDidMount(){}

Comment: I checked the API it returns valid JSON.

Comment: @Jacob The setting of the state is all done inside componentWillMount()

Comment: May I know where you are pushing data into the state stockCharts?

Comment: @HemadriDasari I am calling an api twice, each time getting a JSON object and adding that object to an array of JSON objects (stockCharts). I want to have all of them in one object and handy, thus pushing to state stockCharts

Comment: @bflynnigan componentWillMount() is deprecated and will be phased out. here is the sweet diagram reference for lifecycles. Which shows componentDidMount can handle setting of state or incoming data before a component mounts. http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/

Maybe that will help...

Comment: @Jacob Seems weird that they would deprecate componentWillMount(), as IMO that is the most useful life cycle hook. For instance that is where I do all of my client side authentication and authorization, to make sure that the user must be allowed to access this page before it even renders. Can you elaborate more on why it is being deprecated?

Comment: @bflynnigan that is because the componentDidMount() can now handle the same phase that componentWillMount() would have in React version 16.4 the diagram I shared is super awesome and references those lifecycles documentation like this https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I verified with the api given in my local and I am able to get the data.

First thing the way you push api response to stockCharts is not recommended. Which means direct mutation of the state is not recommended.

You can push api response in the following way

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
   stockCharts: [...prevState.stockCharts, result]
}));
```

Now in render

```
render(){
   this.state.stockCharts.map((data, i) => {
      console.log("data", data); // this will give each object
      console.log("Meta Data", data["Meta Data"]); //This will give meta data information
      console.log("Weekly Time Series", data["Weekly Time Series"]);// this will print weekly time information
   });
   return(

   )
}
```

Is this what your expectation?

Comment: Nice man, this works and I can now do things like `console.log(this.state.stockCharts[0]["Meta Data"])` Cheers boss

Comment: NP. You can also do in that way but since its array of objects I always prefer using map than doing for loop or directly accessing with index position. Glad I am able to help you :)

Comment: @HemadriDasari should logic really be handled in the render, seems like it could be in componentDidMount, I dunno I usually avoid a lot of logic in there.

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you mutate the state which is not recommended.
try instead of calling `this.state.stockCharts.push(result)` do `this.setState({stockCharts: [...this.state.stockCharts, result]})`

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html